# Gravitational forces affecting acceleration on a space ship with artificial gravity

Tags: gravity, artificial-gravity, acceleration

I and my brother are having an argument on gravity on a space ship. For this argument lets say, you are in a void. There are no outside gravity forces, ie planets or solar systems in the near region. You have made a gravity force on your space ship, for example like in the Star Trek, just not as advanced. My argument is if you were to accelerate, you would not be pulled back because you are attached to the gravity of the ship.

There would be no kind of force/gravity pulling you back, so you could go from 1 mph-1000 mph in 1 second, and not be pulled back. My brother thinks, you would be thrown back. The only way I would see this happening is, if the initial acceleration was making a gravitational force pulling you back.

If so would be, could the antigravity around the ship counteract this?

Comment: You translated this text with the google, and then converted to lowercase?

Comment: We have no idea how to produce Star Trek style artificial gravity, so there's no way to reason about its behavior. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I think we could substitute it with the Alcubierre drive. But I think it would require a cooperative OP. Then the essence of the answer would be 1) inertia and gravity are different things 2) impulse conservation still exists in the GR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Star Trek like artificial gravity is science fiction. We don't know of any way to do that with our understanding of physics.

Therefore; both interpretations could be correct, since we don't know anything about the system.

- The system could compensate for the acceleration
- The system could make acceleration irrelevant
- The acceleration could be felt by the users.